# Control CSS with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I currently have some fixed position items on my mobile screen. Now I would like to have a js. routine, which, when running at the startup of the app, determines the version of the operating system (ios4 or ios5). Depending on the system detected, it would choose a css tag such as "margin" and assign it a specific value like "-60" or "0".

How would such a js. script look like?

Thanks

Pierre

Comment: you could do `element.setAttribute("style", "background-color:blue");`

Answer (score 1):

you could use something like this to detect the ios version and change the margin

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iOS 4') != -1){ 
    document.getElementById('target').style.margin = "-60px"
}
```

Comment: You need to make that "-60px" so that all browsers can handle it.